# cudaMalloc of a structure and an element of same structure

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, cuda

I would like to know what happens on the device (memory wise) when I allocate a structure and then **allocate(?) and copy** a pointer element of the same structure.

Do I need `cudaMalloc` of the element ***a** again?

Example code:

```
typedef struct {
  int *a;
  ...
} StructA;

int main() 
{
  int row, col, numS = 10; // defined at runtime

  StructA *d_A = (StructA*)malloc(numS * sizeof(StructA));
  int *h_A = d_a->a;

  cudaMalloc( (void**)&(d_A), numS * sizeof(StructA) );

  cudaMalloc( &(d_A->a), row*col*sizeof(int) ); // no (void**) needed?
  cudaMemcpy( d_A->a, h_A, row*col*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

  kernel<<<grid, block>>>(d_A); // Passing pointer to StructA in device
  ...
}
```

The kernel definition:

```
__global__ kernel(StructA *d_A)
{
  d_A->a = ...;
  ...
}
```

This question is another extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404965/how-to-use-cudamalloc-cudamemcpy-for-a-pointer-to-a-structure-containing-point) and related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078399/cudamalloc-cast-void-and-struct-member-allocation-copy-and-sizeof).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest that you put some effort into compiling and running your codes with proper cuda error checking.  Learning to interpret the compiler output and runtime output will make you a better, smarter, more efficient coder.  I also suggest reviewing the writeup I previously pointed you at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592).  It deals with this exact topic, and includes linked worked examples.  This question is a duplicate of that one.

There are various errors:

```
StructA *d_A = (StructA*)malloc(numS * sizeof(StructA));
```

The above line of code creates an allocation in *host* memory for a structure of size `StructA`, and sets the pointer `d_A` pointing to the start of that allocation.  Nothing wrong at the moment.

```
cudaMalloc( (void**)&(d_A), numS * sizeof(StructA) );
```

The above line of code creates an allocation in *device* memory of the size of `StructA`, and sets the pointer `d_A` pointing to the start of that allocation.  This has effectively wiped out the previous pointer and allocation.  (The previous host allocation is still somewhere, but you can't access it.  It's basically lost.)  Surely that was not your intent.

```
int *h_A = d_a->a;
```

Now that `d_A` (I assume you meant `d_A`, not `d_a`) has been assigned as a device memory pointer, the `->` operation will dereference that pointer to locate the element `a`.  This is *illegal* in host code and will throw an error (seg fault).

```
cudaMalloc( &(d_A->a), row*col*sizeof(int) );
```

This line of code has a similar issue.  We cannot `cudaMalloc` a pointer that lives in device memory.  `cudaMalloc` creates pointers that live in host memory but reference a location in device memory.  This operation `&(d_A->a)` is dereferencing a device pointer, which is illegal in host code.

A proper code would be something like this:

```
$ cat t363.cu
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int *a;
  int foo;
} StructA;

__global__ void kernel(StructA *data){

  printf("The value is %d\n", *(data->a + 2));
}

int main()
{
  int  numS = 1; // defined at runtime

  //allocate host memory for the structure storage
  StructA *h_A = (StructA*)malloc(numS * sizeof(StructA));
  //allocate host memory for the storage pointed to by the embedded pointer
  h_A->a = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
  // initialize data pointed to by the embedded pointer
  for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) *(h_A->a+i) = i;
  StructA *d_A;  // pointer for device structure storage
  //allocate device memory for the structure storage
  cudaMalloc( (void**)&(d_A), numS * sizeof(StructA) );
  // create a pointer for cudaMalloc to use for embedded pointer device storage
  int *temp;
  //allocate device storage for the embedded pointer storage
  cudaMalloc((void **)&temp, 10*sizeof(int));
  //copy this newly created *pointer* to it's proper location in the device copy of the structure
  cudaMemcpy(&(d_A->a), &temp, sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  //copy the data pointed to by the embedded pointer from the host to the device
  cudaMemcpy(temp, h_A->a, 10*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  kernel<<<1, 1>>>(d_A); // Passing pointer to StructA in device
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t363 t363.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t363
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
The value is 2
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

You'll note that I haven't worked out the case where you are dealing with an array of `StructA` (i.e. `numS` >  1), that will require a loop.  I'll leave it to you to work through the logic I've presented here and in my [previous linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592) to see if you can work out the details of that loop.  Furthermore, for the sake of clarity/brevity I've dispensed with the usual [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) but please use it in your codes.  Finally, this process (sometimes called a "deep copy operation") is somewhat tedious in ordinary CUDA if you haven't concluded that yet.  Previous recommendations along these lines are to "flatten" such structures (so that they don't contiain pointers), but you can also explore `cudaMallocManaged` i.e. [Unified Memory in CUDA 6](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/).

Comment: Thanks! This is the ultimate explanation about `cudaMalloc` for me. I really appreciate the time you put in your answer. The allocation lost made with `malloc` with the next `cudaMalloc` is something I have not thought or known previously.

Comment: I am playing with your example code. Since I am in a compute capability 1.3 environment,  and I cannot print from device, I am trying to copy back the modified (e.g: `data->a[2] = 5;`) structure. But, I am not being able to copy back (I thought it would be: `cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, 10*sizeof(StructA), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`)

Comment: That could copy back the structure(s), but it will not copy back the data pointed to by the embedded pointer(s).  If you look at the line of my code that copies that data *to* the device, you should be able to reverse it to retrieve that data from the device.  If you're want to make any progress, you'll need a reasonable understanding of C structures, pointers, and dynamic allocations.  Copying a pointer (which is what is in the structure) does not *also* copy the data pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: I tried doing the following `cudaMemcpy(h_A->a, d_A->a, 10*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);` (among other things). But, I get segmentation error. Thanks for your recommendations, I will follow them and keep brushing my knowledge (long time without practice).

Comment: `d_A->a` requires dereferencing `d_A` which triggers the seg fault.  Try using the `temp` pointer instead.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, as simple as `cudaMemcpy(h_A->a, temp, 10*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`. I need reading more (very disappointed at myself, this feeling of being lost while the answer is right there makes me scare of the future).